# Create Directory With German Umlauts in Php

Tags: php, mysql, directory

I am creating directory with csv following is not a complete codes but sufficient for understanding

1) I am uploading files with city name

2) If set $PageUrl with these names then folder will create with cities name

```
<?php //get the csv file
$file_c = $_FILES['popular_City']['tmp_name'];
$handle_c = fopen($file_c,"r");

$PageUrl = Düsseldorf //this will be admin inputs in csv file 

if (!file_exists($PageUrl)) {
$dir_path = mkdir($PageUrl, 0777, true);

}?>
```

(Insert into database is also working properly I mean folder name)
Into directory output looks like this  `D�sseldorf` (this is folder name )
Note: When I create manually then its working but not with programming Any Solution Guys?

Comment: Thanks for reply dude but I have already done in that way I have problem with folder name not with database

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the encoding, of your database and make sure it is unicode (for instance UTF-8):

```
select table_name,engine 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_database'
```

And make sure you are properly encoding the variable:

```
utf8_encode($string)
```

Also, make sure the CSV file has a proper encoding. In linux do:

```
file -bi [filename]
```

And read a lot about encoding, not many programmers pay attention to it, sadly. I would recommend http://reedbeta.com/blog/programmers-intro-to-unicode/